# avoid reusing setup file in Qt

Tags: qt

I developed a code for android devices.now i want to make a setup file.can I add a piece of code to my app to delete the source file(the setup) after setup is executed?
I want my customer not to access the setup anymore or not being able to use that for other devices, is there other solutions?

Comment: what kind of information is in the setup file? how and when is this information used("setup" is vague)??

Comment: How are you going to prevent the user making a copy of the setup file _before_ installing it?

Comment: @UmNyobe the setup file is the setup of gui application.when setup is executed the info will be used(setup will be made by available softwares which make setup file)

Comment: @Roku i dont prevent it.i just want to avoid reusing 1 file(no solution for those users who copy it) or as i said any other ways to avoid using file for other devices.